# SIM800L EVB audio output on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, speakers, gsm

I have a SIM800L EVB GSM module connected to a Raspberry Pi and it is working correctly. However I did not find any pins related to speaker or audio output as shown in the wiring:

[image]

This is different than the old model which has pins for speaker and audio:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything. The functionality exists on the SoC (SIM(00L)) but is not connected to any external pins on some of the models.

You need to buy a SIM800L module with audio connected from the SoC to external pins.

Ref.: [Datasheet](https://img.filipeflop.com/files/download/Datasheet_SIM800L.pdf)

These are the pins on the underside of the metal capsule (SIM800L SoC.)

[image]